# Simulating the web Client/web server interaction in a winform using a webbrowser object in vb2005.net

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

Simulating the  web Client/web server interaction in a winform using a webbrowser object in vb2005.net

In short I'm using the web browser object as a gui for a giant treeview folder list, in the html there is a form that needs to submit to perform the action, del, rename, etc.

How do I make my program catch the submit, process it and spit out the new info out to the webbrowser item in vb2005 winform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, you set up a net.httplistener
then set it to look at the http://localhost:port

once there you can see the request and response, you then write to the response stream with html headers and the data you want